# Parallel operations over arrays in Julia

Tags: julia

What is the parallel (over multiple CPUs) version of this code in Julia?

```
V = zeros(3)
for i = 1:100000
    cc = rand(1:3)
    V[cc] += 1
end
```

Comment: I'm not certain that loop is actually thread safe - since two processes could grab the same index and try to update it at the same time. You may find [this section](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/index.html#Parallel-Map-and-Loops-1) of the manual and the section it's part of helpful.

Comment: By CPU's do you mean cores or machines?

Comment: @OscarSmith I mean cores.

Comment: @kevbonham It is potentially not safe but other languages have provisions for this, like atomic operations, or making copies of variables for each process and then reducing them safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a direct rewrite of your loop that is thread, tread-safe and avoiding false sharing:

```
using Random
using Base.Threads

V = let
    mt = Tuple([MersenneTwister() for _ in 1:nthreads()])
    Vv = Tuple([zeros(3) for _ in 1:nthreads()])
    @threads for i = 1:100000
        @inbounds cc = rand(mt[threadid()], 1:3)
        @inbounds Vv[threadid()][cc] += 1
    end
    reduce(+, Vv)
end
```

However, in general for such a small job probably using threading will not give you much benefit. Also if you really need performance probably the code should be restructured a bit e.g. like this:

```
function worker(iters, rng)
    v = zeros(3)
    for i = 1:iters
        cc = rand(rng, 1:3)
        v[cc] += 1
    end
    v
end

V = let
    mt = Tuple([MersenneTwister() for _ in 1:nthreads()])
    Vv = [zeros(3) for _ in 1:nthreads()]
    jobs_per_thread = fill(div(100000, nthreads()),nthreads())
    for i in 1:100000-sum(jobs_per_thread)
        jobs_per_thread[i] += 1
    end
    @assert sum(jobs_per_thread) == 100000
    @threads for i = 1:nthreads()
        Vv[threadid()] = worker(jobs_per_thread[threadid()], mt[threadid()])
    end
    reduce(+, Vv)
end
```

Also under Julia 1.3 you will not have to do manual `MersenneTwister` management, as Julia will create separate PRNG per thread.

Comment: Thanks! This first version works. The second version returns `ERROR: LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 1-element Array{Int64,1} at index [0]
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:728 ` error. The actual code is more complicated I just wanted to figure out how these things are done on a very simple example.

Comment: Also, will this automatically use all the available CPU cores?

Comment: In the second code please make sure that you copy-paste exactly what I have passed after you refresh the page (it works on my machine) and let me know if it works for you. The code will use the number of cores that you tell Julia to use. You set the number of thread by setting `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` environment variable. Here you have a reference https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/#Setup-1.

Comment: Thanks @BogumiłKamiński. What is the reason for `Vv = Tuple([zeros(3) for _ in 1:nthreads()])` instead of `Vv = Tuple([zeros(3) for _ in 1:nthreads()])`?

Comment: can you please clarify? You have pasted the same code twice.